# Problems using App Compat theme instead of Material Theme

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to use Material theme for my app and target from Jelly Bean to "M".

What's the correct recommendation ?
1. Use appcompat theme on api levels below 21 and use standard material them on 21 and above
2) Simply use appcompat on all the api levels.

Will I be missing anything if I simply use appcompat on all api levels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use only the AppCompat themes for all. For most stylings, they have their own implementations that mimic more modern approaches. For things that can't be mimicked, they just simply don't do it or move to the default (one that comes to mind is the Ripple effect. 21+ devices it will use Ripple, but on others it will default to the standard button selector). If they can use native approaches, then they will use those instead.

On some cases though, you may need to create styles that contain attributes which unique to a certain API level.  In which case you need to create a `layout-v##` folder where `##` is the API level to support.  Then put in a Style with the same name as one in the lower `layout` folder. Android will choose the appropriate folder. The same can be done for any other resource folder.

Answer (score 2):

Use AppCompat for everything, there is built in functionality to handle if you are using < 21 or >= 21.

Really the only time you should use the standard Material Theme is if your base API you support is 21+ but even then you will eventually use app compat for new things that get added